# Can the Github syntax highlighting scheme be changed?

Tags: github

Is there a way to change the color scheme on Github for syntax highlighting? I have done a basic search and could not find an answer.

Comment: Client-side for yourself (i.e. when you browse someone's Github repo) or server-side for others (i.e. when others browse your Gitcode repo)?

Comment: My question is primarily concerned with server-side. I would like to display the code in my Github repo in a different color scheme.

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no way to change the color scheme server-side.

---

Several users of github.com have already asked for **custom grammars** ([#2627](https://github.com/github/linguist/issues/2627) and [#2598](https://github.com/github/linguist/issues/2598)), which, depending on the solution proposed, may also mean being able to change the color scheme. There are, however, some technical and legal concerns to address before this could be implemented (see [#2627](https://github.com/github/linguist/issues/2627) in particular).

If you wanted to do this **client-side**, you could use a browser extension to change the color scheme. Of course, this would require all users to download an install that extension.